# Disable Apple PHP on Mac OS and use XAMPP instead

Tags: php, macos

Hi I've installed XAMPP and I want to use the PHP that comes with it from the command line.

So I'm looking to disable the Apple version of PHP and related tools.

Anyone know a clean way of doing this, while allowing Apples PHP to be re-enabled again relatively easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning off web-sharing (Sys Prefs -> Sharing) will let you set XAMPP to listen on :80, and it will use it's own version of PHP.

For CLI, you can setup an alias in your .profile to point at the XAMPP version or put the XAMPP bin folder (wherever the php executable is found...) in your PATH, ahead of /usr/bin

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to uninstall the apple php package. You can reinstall it anytime...
Of course you would have to tell osx to use XAMPP 's php interpreter instead of 
the on board one.

Basically [this](http://www.silverspider.com/2004/change-file-associations-in-os-x/) should be sufficent to achieve the change in the file handling.